# How to print 1st and 4th variable only if 4th variable is > or equal to 25

Tags: awk

```
Networking:            [Test] => 10.729519791085

GAMES:            [Real] => 10

Fashion:            [Test] => 27.729519791085

Movies:            [Real] => 5

Food:            [Test] => 101.729519791085

Sports:            [Real] => 7
```

How to print 1st and 4th variable if value is greater or equal 25.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ awk '$4 >= 25 {print $1,$4}' file
Fashion: 27.729519791085
Food: 101.729519791085
```